# Wget: memory exhausted error on Windows

Tags: windows, wget

When mirroring certain sites with wget on Windows 7, I am getting a good portion of the site, but it then fails with a memory exhausted error.  Has anyone else run into this and if so how did you fix it?  I am more than willing to go into the source code if necessary.

I know this error has occurred in the past on Linux, but I can find no relevant answers to Windows.